# Creating an custom Integromat app: multiple-requests, limit reading according to the bundle number

Tags: make.com

I'm building a multi-request app, and I want the first call to be only on the first run. That is, if in the scenario the module operates on more than one bundle, from the second bundle onwards only the second call will be made and not the first (if there is an option for higher flexibility, that I can define in which runs both calls will run and in which runs one of them will run - that is better).

Do you think this is possible?
Is it possible to insert the bundle number into the application?